# Как сделать обработчик нажатий на CardView, созданные программно

Tags: android, cardview, loader

Подскажите, как сделать обработчик нажатий на CardView, созданные программно. Они расположены не подряд списком, а располагаются в RelativeLayout под нужными элементами.
Загружаю их лоадером

```
ArrayList<CardView> card = new ArrayList<CardView>();
int count;

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    count = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            //здесь считываю данные и расчитываю на какой высоте выставлять
            card.add((CardView)cv.findViewById(R.id.cardview));
            card.get(count).getLayoutParams().height = здесь высота
            card.get(count).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //отсюда запускаю фрагмент с описанием этой cardview
                }
            });
            ++count;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

в итоге выход за пределы (invalid index)

Comment: Вы делаете совершенно неправильно. Для организации списков, выводящих информацию из базы данных используется `ListView` с `SimpleCursorAdapter` или `RecyclerView`. Поверьте, это в 100 раз удобнее того, чем вы сейчас занимаетесь

Comment: @msp, зачем у Вас переменная `count` вынесена за пределы метода? И Вы не создаёте карточки программно, а выдёргиваете одну и ту же: `cv.findViewById(R.id.cardview)` - то есть весь список будет содержать кучу ссылок на одну карточку. Отсюда и "invalid index" - так как нельзя одну вью добавить в контейнер дважды.

Comment: карточки создаются View cv = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.event, r_ayout, false); и отрисовываются без проблем. А вот обработчик не могу сделать. Они не списком идут, а раскиданы по макету, в этом проблема. ListView и RecyclerView знаю, но не пойму как их сюда прикрутить

Comment: Но всё же в `onLoadFinished` Вы обращаетесь к одной и той же карточке, поскольку берёте её из одного контейнера `cv`. Думаю Вам нужно список `card` заполнять сразу при создании их инфлейтером. А вообще покажите стектрейс ошибки и больше кода - из этого куска мало что понятно

Answer (score 3):

Программно `View` создаются либо конструктором:

```
  View view = new View(context);
```

либо из xml с помощью `LayoutInflater`:

```
  View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.filename, root);
```